# reload just a part of a page after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am trying to add a search module for my data listing .

my function that i post the request to, renders a view.

how can i load the list grid after pushing search button?

should i `echo` a `html` code, or render a view and write that view in that position?

I am totally confused ...

```
public function actionSell() {
    $cond="";
    if($_POST) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_POST[$key] = str_replace(',', '', stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($value)));
        }
        $melk_id = $_POST['melk_id'];
        $city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
        $cost_from = $_POST['cost_from'];
        $cost_to = $_POST['cost_to'];
        $metraj_from = $_POST['metraj_from'];
        $metraj_to = $_POST['metraj_to'];
        if($melk_id) $cond .= ' and melk_id='.$melk_id; 
        if($city_id) $cond .= ' and city_id='.$city_id;
        if($cost_from) $cond .= ' and cost >='.$cost_from;
        if($cost_to) $cond .= ' and cost <='.$cost_to;
        if($metraj_from) $cond .= ' and metraj >='.$metraj_from;
        if($metraj_to) $cond .= ' and metraj <='.$metraj_to;
    }
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Data', array('criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'type = 0 '.$cond,
            'order' => 'id DESC',
        ),
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 15)
    ));
    $this->render('sell', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a php developer but I'll try yo answer in a jQuery manner.

1. Suppose you hold your list grid in a container:  `<div id="container"> //the grid </div>`
2. You fill the container from a `View`  that holds **the grid**
3. You have **Seach TextBox**
   `<input id="searchBox" type="text" name="SeachTxt" Value="Some text"/>`

   **And a Button :**
   `<input id="SearchBtn" type="button" value="Search Now!">`
4. Next you must have a jQuery ajax post function, like this one:

   ```
   jQuery("#SearchBtn").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?searchString=' + jQuery("#searchBox").val(),
       success: function(result) {
           jQuery("#container").html(result);
       }
   });
   ```

   });

Answer (score 2):

you could use `renderPartial`, like

```
$this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array(
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
                    ), false, true
);
```

Comment: how would i use it in my  jquery request?